# Throwing ambiguous error for multiple joins in Rails 3.2.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a query:

```
User.select("distinct username as value, username as foto, roles.user_id as ID, 
followers as follower ").
where("username ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:term]}%").
joins(:identities).joins(:roles).all(conditions:{roles:{name: 'Creator'}})
```

But `user_id` is getting an error because I assume that it is also being used by `identities` table.

How can I actually specify that `user_id` column is just for the query of `roles` table?

Any workarounds will be appreciated.

EDIT:

Log:

```
Rendered campaigns/_campaign_new.html.haml (27.7ms)
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT distinct username as value, user_id as ID, username as foto FROM "users" INNER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles_users"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "roles" ON "roles"."id" = "roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "roles"."name" = 'Creator' AND (username ILIKE '%%')
  User Load (1.9ms)  SELECT distinct username as value, username as foto, user_id as ID, followers as follower FROM "users" INNER JOIN "identities" ON "identities"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles_users"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "roles" ON "roles"."id" = "roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "roles"."name" = 'Creator' AND (username ILIKE '%%')
PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "user_id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: ...ECT distinct username as value, username as foto, user_id as...
                                                             ^
: SELECT distinct username as value, username as foto, user_id as ID, followers as follower  FROM "users" INNER JOIN "identities" ON "identities"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles_users"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "roles" ON "roles"."id" = "roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "roles"."name" = 'Creator' AND (username ILIKE '%%')
  Rendered campaigns/new.js.erb (38.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 51ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "user_id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: ...ECT distinct username as value, username as foto, user_id as...
                                                             ^
: SELECT distinct username as value, username as foto, user_id as ID, followers as follower  FROM "users" INNER JOIN "identities" ON "identities"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles_users"."user_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "roles" ON "roles"."id" = "roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "roles"."name" = 'Creator' AND (username ILIKE '%%'):
```

Comment: This happened to me when I had a default order on my model. Can you post the exact query that's being executed? You can find it in the log.

Comment: @musicnerd47 Or you can simply add `.to_sql` to the code above and run it in console.

Comment: @BroiSatse interesting! I had never seen that.

Comment: @xirukitepe, could you please paste the exact error message? Your code do specify which table user_id is on, so that shouldn't be the problem. Which of users, identities or roles tables have 'username' column - and more importantly, is it defined only on one of those tables?

Comment: Quick question, have you recently changed `user_id` to `roles.user_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `users.id` or `roles_users.user_id`:

```
User.select("distinct username as value, username as foto, users.id as ID ...
```

Comment: OMG. Saved my life. I was hitting different table associations for a long time.